# Does one-to-one transformation means its matrix is regular?

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations

Suppose that $T(v):=Av$  is one-to-one from $F^n$ to $F^n$ (A is a matrix) That is **not** surjective.

Does that mean that $A$ is regular?

**On the one hand:**

$T$ is One-To-One $\implies\ker(T)=\{0\} \implies$ only $v=0$ solves $Av=0 \implies A$ is regular

**On the other hand:**

$T$ is not surjective $\implies$ there exists $b$ such that for each $v$, $T(v)=Av\neq b$.
Therefore, $A$ is not regular.

Which of these proofs is wrong and why?

Thanks!

Comment: Linear mappings between finite dimensional vector spaces with the same dimension are always either both injective and surjective or neither injective nor surjective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assumption that there exists a one-to-one linear transformation that is not surjective from $F^n$ to $F^n$ is false. You can see this by using the rank-nullity theorem and the fact that the kernel is trivial. Since they don't exist both statements are vacuously true.